# How to create dynamic columns for the missing ones in the Sink SQL table in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have to move excel data to SQL table. There are scenarios where the input excel file have missing columns which are present in the sink SQL table. In this case, I have to compare columns for each input excel file with columns in sink SQL table, if there are any missing columns in the excel sheet then I have to add dynamically the column and then store the data in the sink SQL table.

For instance,
Input excel file contain 3 columns, A, B, and C whereas the sink SQL table contains 4 columns A, B, C, and D which means D is missing in the excel file and thus in such cases D column should get added with blank entries and then should get store in the sink SQL table.

I have tried multiple ways to lookup and then make changes in the copy activity but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below approach to achieve your requirement.

Here, as you want to copy multiple excel files, you need to use a For loop.
These are my excel files in source.

**Sample1.xlsx**

```
A   B   C
1   Laddu   22
2   ABD 39
```

**Sample2.xlsx**

```
A   C   D
1   Dell    22
2   HP  39
```

In SQL table, I have 5 columns `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`.

You can use **Additional columns in copy activity source**. But for this you need to build to required columns array and it requires another loop for every file. So, we need to use a child pipeline(ADF doesn't support nested loops currently).

In Parent pipeline, use Get meta data activity to get the files list, Pass this array to ForEach.

- Inside ForEach, use lookup activity(check FirstRow in it) for excel to get the columns of the file. Use dataset parameters for the dynamic filename(use `@item().name` in the lookup inside Foreach) and also uncheck the First row as header in the dataset.
  [image]
- This will give the columns of the file and next, use Get Meta data activity to get the structure of the SQL table.
  [image]
- Now, use Filter activity to filter the column names of the SQL table which are not exists in the excel file.
- If the Filter array count is greater than 0, it means we have missing columns in the excel file otherwise the copy should be normal.
- Check the Filter array count condition using `if activity` and inside `True activities` of if, use the Execute pipeline activity. In the child pipeline create an empty array parameter and pass the filter output array from the Parent pipeline to child through Execute pipeline activity.

Now, in Child pipeline, create an empty array variable from the pipeline variables list. We use this array to store the column name and value which we should give to the copy activity in next step.

- Give the array parameter which created in last step to the ForEach in child pipeline.
- Inside ForEach, use an **append variable activity** to the array variable and give the below expression.

  ```
  @json(concat('{"name":"',item().name,'","value": ""}'))
  ```

  [image]
- After, ForEach, return this array variable to the parent pipeline like below.

  [image]
- We can access this variable using `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.columns_arr` expression. Use this expression in the Additional columns of the copy activity source.
  [image]
  Use another Excel dataset(Check first row as header for this) for the source of the copy activity and for dynamic file name use dataset parameters and give the file name like above.
- Inside the **False activities of if** give the same copy activity without any additional columns.

**Result SQL table:**

[image]

**NOTE:** Make sure you check **Sequential** checkbox in both Foreach activities.

Use the below pipeline JSONs to implement the above approach.

**Parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get excel filenames",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get excel filenames').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "ExcelSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    }
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "Excel_for_lookup",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "SQL_sink",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "structure"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Filter1",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@not(contains(string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow), item().name))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filter1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(activity('Filter1').output.FilteredItemsCount, 0)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifFalseActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Copy data2",
                                        "type": "Copy",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "source": {
                                                "type": "ExcelSource",
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                    "recursive": true,
                                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                                "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                                "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                            },
                                            "enableStaging": false,
                                            "translator": {
                                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                                "typeConversion": true,
                                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "inputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "Excel_for_copy_activity",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "filename": {
                                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "outputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "SQL_sink",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Copy data1",
                                        "type": "Copy",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "source": {
                                                "type": "ExcelSource",
                                                "additionalColumns": {
                                                    "type": "Expression",
                                                    "value": "@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.columns_arr"
                                                },
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                    "recursive": true,
                                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                                "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                                "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                            },
                                            "enableStaging": false,
                                            "translator": {
                                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                                "typeConversion": true,
                                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "inputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "Excel_for_copy_activity",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "filename": {
                                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "outputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "SQL_sink",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                        "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "pipeline": {
                                                "referenceName": "Child",
                                                "type": "PipelineReference"
                                            },
                                            "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                            "parameters": {
                                                "filter_array": {
                                                    "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.value",
                                                    "type": "Expression"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get excel filenames",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Excel_for_getmetadata",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "columns_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Child Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.filter_array",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "columns_arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{\"name\":\"',item().name,'\",\"value\": \"\"}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "columns_arr",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@variables('columns_arr')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "filter_array": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "columns_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```